# PlayFramework - Show message without refresh page

Tags: javascript, playframework, partial-page-refresh, twirl

In fact, I would post after processing a form for example, processed the information and return a flash without refreshing the page with the new information in case of failure. If the form is valid then I refer to another page for example.

I put myself on the web a short time ago. I think that refreshing information on a page without refreshing the page completely will be useful in the future.

[I have a video in order to illustrate what i'm saying.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2_MCmFpyt0)

> If you have sample of code, i take :D

Code (optional reading) :

Html:

```
@module.note.render(PanelType.DANGER, "contact")
<form id="submit" class="submit-form" method="post" action="@routes.SupportController.postSupport()">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <label class="control-label">Votre nom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="">
        </div>
    ...
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <label class="control-label">Votre message</label>
            <p>
                <textarea id="content" name="content" placeholder="Ecrivez votre message ici"></textarea>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        CKEDITOR.replace('content');
                </script>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->

    <hr class="invis">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Envoyer !</button>
</form>
```

postSupport() function :

```
@Http.Post
    public Result postSupport()
    {
        DynamicForm d = form.form().bindFromRequest();
        FormChecker errors = new Support().getErrors(new FormValidator(d));
        List<String> check = errors.check();
        if(check != null && !check.isEmpty())
        {
            flash("contact", check.get(0));
            return index();
        }
        Support support = new Support(d.get("lastName"), d.get("email"), d.get("content"), d.get("subject"), d.get("website"), d.get("department"));
        support.insert();
        return supportList();
    }
```

getErrors() function :

```
@Override
public FormChecker getErrors(FormValidator f)
{
    return new FormChecker(f,
            x -> x.validate("lastName", "content", "email", "subject", "website", "department"),
            x -> x.isValidEmail("email"),
              x -> x.isValidUrl("website"),
            x -> x.isValidMinbLenght(5, "subject")
                ? "" : "Le sujet doit avoir une longueur minimum de 5 caractères.",
            x -> x.isValidMinbLenght(30, "content")
                ? "" : "Le contenu du rapport doit faire minimum 30 caractères.",
            x -> x.isValidMinbLenght(3, "lastName")
                ? "" : "Votre nom doit avoir une longueur minimum de 5 caractères.",
            x -> new SupportDepartment().get("department", x.get("department")) != null
                ? "" : "Le département n'éxiste pas."
    );
}
```

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Can you post your javascript code to submit the form?

Comment: At the moment i have doing nothing for javascript side, juste html <-> PlayFramework. I search a sample of code which work with play framework :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to check the inputs, and then if everything is OK send the form.

```
function check(){
   if(arguments are valid) sendResults();
   else showErrors;
}
```

It would help if you showed a minimum version of the code, for example what action is fired when the button is clicked.

Comment: I'm doing lamda verification, email validation, minimum check but i don't want the verification in javascript ! Because i have some code for that in backend side..

Comment: In that case I'm afraid I cannot help you, sorry.